# google app script save the checkbox string

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to coding in google app script and what I need is to save the checkbox string if checkbox is true then I want to save the value string for it

for example I add two checkboxes,

mail and female if I checked the mail checkbox I want to save the string mail and not if it's true or false

this is my code

```
 // Save Data
     function submitData() {


     var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var formSS  = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry"); //Form Sheet
     var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet

      //Input Values
    var values = [[formSS.getRange("C5").getValue(),

    // get the checkbox value
             formSS.getRange("G5").getValue(), 

     // get the checkbox string value = mail

           formSS.getRange("I7").getValue(),

        // get the checkbox value

             formSS.getRange("J7").getValue(),

       // get the checkbox string value = female

             formSS.getRange("K7").getValue() ,
            
            

                   ]];
            
            
            
            datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 4).setValues(values);
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(' "New Data Saved  ) );     
            
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

With this data validation:

[image]

and this code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.value);
  }
}
```

You get this table as you edit column 3:

[image]